# specialized AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate(_:) + 13348544

Tags: ios, swift

In XCode organizer,see the crashes of my app. There are many crashes on iOS15.I can't reproduce it on my iOS15 device. I guess it crashed when the application on the background because the log shows the app delegate terminate function time and crash time. The crash log is in the attachment. I cannot get some useful info from the log. can you help me, please

[Xcode Organizer screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuPCz.jpg)
[Error captured from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xju4W.png)

Comment: "I cannot get some useful info from the log"  You aren't alone.

Comment: @ElTomato please check the attached screenshot for more details

Comment: Did you find a solution, we're also struggeling with background crashes in iOS 15.